# Get Key Name Length Google App Engine NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm currently trying to use ComputedProperties to obtain the length of the my key name which is a collection of letters from example xyz using the below code.

```
ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda e: len(e.get_by_id))
```

The issue I'm having is I cant seem to find a way of access the key within the model to get its length and then define this as a Computer Property.

I thought of storing the key as a string within the model but that duplicates things for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an `@property`?:

```
@property
def key_length(self):
   return len( self.key.string_id() )
```

or lambda:

```
ndb.ComputedProperty( lambda self: len( self.key.string_id() ) )
```

This solves the question

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That returns the following error. TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len(). Removing len() returns <bound method Key.string_id of Key('List', 'dgo')>. I can't seem to get the string dgo out of it.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Forgot a `(`.  Good edit.  Added spaces to highlight the parentheses groupings.